# Se puede actualizar el componentDidMount en react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, usestate

Estoy intentando actualizar mi componentDidMount pero no puedo no se cual sea mi error. Al seleccionar una membresia, un ciclo de facturación desde un picker y un checkbox para incluir los folios cancelados, aqui les dejo mi código del `componentDidMount:`

```
async componentDidMount() {
  const membresiaId = this.state.membresiaSeleccionada;
  const cicloFacturacionId = this.state.CicloFacturacionSeleccionada;
  const incluirFoliosCancelados = this.state.incluirFolio;
  const facturaService = new FacturacionService;
  const membresiasService = new MembresiaService;
  var response = await facturaService.ObtenerListado(membresiaId, cicloFacturacionId, incluirFoliosCancelados);
  var responseMembresias = await membresiasService.ObtenerListado();
  var responseCicloFacturacion = await facturaService.ObtenerCicloFactura();
  this.setState({
    Facturas: response.Facturas,
    MembresiasModel: responseMembresias.Membresias,
    CicloFacturacionModel: responseCicloFacturacion.CiclosDeFacturacion,
  });
}
```

Esta es mi función para aplicar los cambios y que actualice el estado de la membresia, el ciclo de facturación y el folio cancelado:

```
aplicarCambios() { 
  this.setState({ 
    modalVisible: false, 
    membresiaSeleccionada: this.state.membresiaSeleccionada, 
    CicloFacturacionSeleccionada: this.state.CicloFacturacionSeleccionada, 
    incluirFolio: this.state.incluirFolio 
  })
}
```

Aquí inicio mi estado con valores predefinidos para la api y son los que quiero cambiar al presionar el botón para `aplicarCambios():`

```
constructor(props: Props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    incluirFolio: false,
    Facturas: [],
    modalVisible: false,
    MembresiasModel: [],
    membresiaSeleccionada: 56,
    CicloFacturacionModel: [],
    CicloFacturacionSeleccionada: 0,
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

He solucionado mi problema cambiando el listado de las facturas a otra función de esta manera:

```
async actualizarListado() {
  const membresiaId = this.state.membresiaSeleccionada;
  const cicloFacturacionId = this.state.CicloFacturacionSeleccionada;
  const incluirFoliosCancelados = this.state.incluirFolio;
  const facturaService = new FacturacionService;
  var response = await facturaService.ObtenerListado(membresiaId, cicloFacturacionId, incluirFoliosCancelados);
  
  this.setState({
    Facturas: response.Facturas
  })
}

async componentDidMount() {
  const facturaService = new FacturacionService;
  const membresiasService = new MembresiaService;
  var responseMembresias = await membresiasService.ObtenerListado();
  var responseCicloFacturacion = await facturaService.ObtenerCicloFactura();
  this.setState({
    MembresiasModel: responseMembresias.Membresias,
    CicloFacturacionModel: responseCicloFacturacion.CiclosDeFacturacion
  });
  this.actualizarListado();
}
```

Y cuando quiero actualizar el estado de ese listado lo hago mediante un botón `onPress={() => this.aplicarCambios()}` de esta manera:

```
aplicarCambios() {
  this.actualizarListado();
  this.setState({ 
    modalVisible: false, 
  })
}
```